# What is the meaning of "perhaps" here? "[The solution] is valid in the common interval of convergence ... except perhaps for $x=x_0$ ..."

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

> [image: theorem assuring the existence of Frobenius series Soln]

I am unclear about why won't a Frobenius series solution be valid at $x=x_0$ or why is it uncertain at $x=x_0$?  In the theorem it is stated as "except perhaps at $x=x_0$". I haven't studied real analysis yet, so I might be missing out important information.

Comment: A solution may go to $\infty$ at $x_0$.

Comment: why might it go to infinity at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution may go to $\infty$ at $_0$.

**Example.**  $x_0 = 0$,  consider the differential equation
$$
x^2 y''(x)+3xy'(x)+y(x) = 0 .
$$
Frobenius series solutions are:
$$
y_1(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \dots\\
y_2(x) = \frac{\log x}{x} +\dots
$$
so they go to $\infty$ at $x=0$.  [In fact in this simple case, the $\dots$ are all zeros.]

Comment: so there is no solution at $x_0$ ?

Comment: The general solution is: $C_1y_1+C_2y_2$.  The only solution that does not blow up at $0$ is the constant zero solution.  So (as the exercise says) the Frobenius series solutions are valid except at $0$.